# Ballerina support message ID?

Tags: ballerina

Does ballerina provide unique identified ID? This should help to identify the message flow. If it is support, what is the scope of that uuid?

Comment: Is this related to HTTP or JMS or something else ? What did you meant by message flow ?
You can generate a UUID using the ballerina/system package if you are looking for one.
https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/system.html#uuid

Comment: Can you describe your requirement in detail please?

Comment: We need to track each and every message server by ballerina. And per each request we send events to Analyser for analytics and throttling. In that case we need to identify requested separately. And also we send events in multiple places like in request path, response path or a fault happen. In that case we need to co-related those events

Comment: If your events are HTTP, then you can use http headers to have a custom header with a uuid value.

Answer (score 0):

If your events are HTTP, then you can use http headers to have a custom header with a UUID value(https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/http.html#Request-setHeader).

If your events are JMS, you can use the correlation ID JMS header(https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/jms.html#Message-setCorrelationID) with a UUID.